# Script for sending discord message

Tags: javascript, discord, dom-events, contenteditable

I would like to create JavaScript script (not bot) executable from web browser console. This script should send some message in currently opened channel. My code looks like this:

```js
const editable = document.querySelector('main [contenteditable]') // Locate textfield for message.
editable.focus()

document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Inserted text...\n\n') // Simulate typing of "Inserted text...\n\n".

editable.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13 })) // Simulate enter for sending message.
```

When I run it, text is typed into the field, however it still behaves as it would be empty (there is placeholder and it's not possible to send this message using Enter):

[image]

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: This is against the discord TOS. If you create any script to A: modify the client or B: send requests to Discord automatically it is considered "non-official clients" and can end in termination of your account.

Comment: And, Discord is built with React. Editing react components with the DOM will cause React to give up and the app will freeze.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am trying to make a userscript for a custom emote handler and can't for the life of me figure out how to add text to the message box.

Comment: @RootInit Unfortunately I didn't.